# How can I replace just the css selector with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to replace just the `height` attribute to `min-height`

this is how I would normally change the value, but not sure how to change the attribute

```
 $('.mySelector').css('height','650px')

<div class="mySelector" style="cursor: -moz-grab; width: 1266px; height: 650px;">
```

My apologies should have mentioned this earlier

Comment: There is no _min-height_ attribute.

Comment: it will only append to the attributes but i need to replace height to min height

Comment: Are you confused regarding css values, like height, or is this an actual attribute in the HTML ?

Comment: The styles added by javascript inline in the HTML

Comment: So it's a style, not an attribute, like `<img height="200" />` where height is an actual attribute, where as `<img style="height: 200px" />` would be a css value. This is pertinent information, and could invalidate some of the answers below that are looking for an actual attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have your height set in the `height` attribute, I think you'd have to do something like this:

```
var selector = $('.mySelector');

// set the min-height to I guess whatever the height you had set was
selector.css('min-height', selector.attr('height'));

// remove that old height attribute
selector.removeAttr('height');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the height attribute but add the same value to the min-height *style* attribute, you could do this:

```
$('.mySelector').css('min-height', function() {
    return this.height;
}).removeAttr('height');
```

Comment: You'd need to do `this.getAttribute('height');` But I like it +1

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS why? `height` is a direct property of the element.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS right, I was assuming it was an image... http://jsfiddle.net/DYHEC/1/

Comment: Ahh! Does work for that you're right. Strange it doesn't work for even a dom element like textarea or input.

Comment: not sure why this is working for me, the height attribute I'm trying to change is inline added by javascript

Comment: `element.height` gets the actual height of the elements, as in the height set by your inline css, that's why it's working. So would `element.style.height` by the way.